# Parse an xml in C using string functions

Tags: c, string, substring

I have an xml file which I have to read and parse to find out one value.

I have this value mentioned within tags at two places in the file as follows:

```
<length>xx</length>

<length type = "float">yy</length>
```

I need to extract xx and yy. I am using simple string functions(owing to size restrictions I cant use xml Parsers).

What string functions would help me extract xx and yy?

I tried strtok() on these lines but without success..:

```
fp = fopen( "trial.xml", "r" );
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("file missing");
    }


    while (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp) != NULL) {
                char *p;
            p = strstr(buffer, "<length");
            if(p != NULL){
            printf("p = %s\n", p);
            p = strtok (p, "<>");
            printf("strtok 1, p = %s\n", p);
            p = strtok (NULL, "<>");
            printf("p = %s\n", p);
         }
```

Comment: Feel free to select an answer to some of your previous questions. That's generally how this site works.

Comment: "owing to size restrictions I cant use xml Parsers".. why these restrictions? You can't simply use something as small as TinyXML?

Comment: Yeah, I think you should use a parser

Comment: ok let me check TinyXML :) any other suggestions?

Comment: Any minimal C library(xml parser?)?

Comment: @user Just use TinyXML for a test and tell us in full detail why it does not suit your needs in case it doesn't. It's simple enough to use for a quick test and very pleasant IMHO. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using TinyXML to do your parsing.

If you want to use brute force...

```
fp = fopen( "trial.xml", "r" );
if(!fp) {
    perror("file missing");
}

while(fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp)) {
    if(strstr(buffer, "<length>")) {
        char* start = strchr(buffer, '>');
        start++;
        char* end = strchr(buffer, '<');
        end = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", start);      // prints xx
    }
    if(strstr(buffer, "<length type = \"float\">")) {
        char* start = strchr(buffer, '>');
        start++;
        char* end = strchr(buffer, '<');
        end = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", start);      // prints yy
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I changed a few places to make it work. Used strtok for char*end instead of strchr. Also strchr needs "a character" so changed "<" to '<'